# How to convert text file to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I have a .html file and want to show only 1 object value. The html file doesnt have any tag because its reading data database and only have simple format.

SPractice=0&SLive=0&OnlineU=349

Is there any way to read only value of OnlineU? Is there any way to get this value using javascript or classic asp?

Comment: javascript or classic asp? Both are possible with regex, it's you who need to decide if you want to get the file on server or client side!

Answer (score 0):

That's not HTML.  Nor is it XML or JSON, so you have to use a customer parser on the server or the client.

From parsing a similar format in JavaScript, I know you can it with regex. However, the corner cases are tricky if the values can have special characters e.g. an escaped equal sign).  Look at [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), and be sure to use a cross-browser split method [like this](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split).

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```
 var s='SPractice=0&SLive=0&OnlineU=349';
 eval (s.replace(/&/g,';'));
 alert(OnlineU);
```

Comment: yes!! but the value of that file changes quite frequently. So I cant actually define the "var s" value. Is there any way to get the value from that file only

Comment: Surround it with jquery get: 

`$.get('test.html', function(data) {
 eval (data.replace(/&/g,';'));
 alert(OnlineU);
});`

Comment: $.get('test.html', function(data) { eval (data.replace(/&/g,';')); alert(OnlineUser); }); I'm getting error data.replace is not a function. Please correct me wher m wrong.

Comment: it prob. means that data is null. Have you replaced test.html with actual URL of your page? If yes, please put breakpoint on first row of function and see what is the data.

Comment: Code in test.html 
Success=true&amp;MLive=0&amp;SPractice=777286&amp;SmeterLive=0&amp;OnlineUser=735

Code in result page - 
<script>$(function () { $("#result").load("counter.html");$('<p></p>').appendTo('.text'); });</script>
<div id="result"></div>

I am not able to figure out mistake. Please suggest.

Comment: Try following:

In test.html
`Success=true&MLive=0&SPractice=777286&SmeterLive=0&OnlineUser=73‌​5`

In result page        
`<script>$(function () {
    $(function () {
        $.get('test.html', function (data) {
            eval(data.replace(/&/g, ';'));
            $('#result').text(OnlineUser);
        })
    });
});
</script>


<div id="result"></div>
`

Comment: using eval this way is madness. it can lead to many errors and security holes.

Comment: Is there any way with classic asp if Jquery is problem?

Comment: WOW!!  Its working no..woohoo!! super buddy :) much appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery BBQ plugin:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html#jQuery.deparam

you can use it like this:

```
var string = "SPractice=0&SLive=0&OnlineU=349";

$(function() {
    alert($.deparam(string, true)['OnlineU']); //alerts 349
});
```

It covers pretty much every corner case.

EDIT: Since you are already using jQuery try this.

```
$.get('test.html', function(data) { 
    alert('Raw data: ' + data); //Should alert the raw data
    var onlineu = $.deparam(string, true)['OnlineU'];
    alert('OnlineU: ' + onlineu); //Should alert 349 or something like that.
}, dataType: 'text');
```

Comment: but the value of that file changes quite frequently. So I cant actually define the "var s" value.

Comment: That was just an example to show you how can it parse the string. Are you having trouble reading the file content with javascript? I can help with that too.

Comment: Much Appreciated!! Here is code
Code in test.html 

Success=true&amp;MLive=0&amp;SPractice=777286&amp;SmeterLive=0&amp;OnlineUser=73‌​5 

Code in result page - <script>$(function () { $("#result").load("counter.html");$('<p></p>').appendTo('.text'); });</script> <div id="result"></div> 

I am not able to figure out mistake. Please suggest.

Comment: What result page what are you talking about? You are opening test.html in a browser and getting those script tags or what? Please edit your question and explain it in details.

Comment: I am having two pages namely counter.html and index.html.  Counter.html has raw data - 
Success=true&MLive=0&SPractice=777286&SmeterLive=0&OnlineUser=735

I want to show OnlineUser value that's 735 in index.html. Note - I can declare the value as the counter.html value changes periodically.

Comment: With code you provided my getting - 
Raw data: [object XMLDocument] as alert value. Its not working either.

Comment: Terrific. But maybe you could tell how it is 'not working'. Does it alert the contents of the test.html? If not what does it alert? Have you tried to DEBUG the javascript? With chrome developer tools or firebug for example. Are you getting any errors there?